# Naudio C#: How do I accurately sync a StopWatch with the audio playback progress?

Tags: c#, naudio

I am working on a rythm game, which means I want screen elements to displayed to the beat. For that I need to be able to tell where on the timeline of the music I currently am. I am using the Naudio library (ASIO to be more specific) and I know that I can call the `CurrentTime` field of the `WaveStream` I'm currently playing to find out how much time has passed since the music started playing, however that Field doesn't seem to be very accurate (at least not nearly accurate enough to fluently display a moving screen element) as it's just an approximation based on the average bytes per second. that's why I'm trying to sync a `StopWatch` to the music instead. However, no matter what I try I always get an offset. My current setup works like this:

```
var audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader("music.mp3");
var waveChannel32 = new WaveChannel32(audioFileReader); //
var asioOut = new AsioOut(0);
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
asioOut.Init(waveChannel32);
asioOut.Play();
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
waveChannel32.Position = 0;
stopWatch.Start();
```

If I then compare `stopWatch.Elapsed` with `waveChannel32.CurrentTime` it looks like the `stopWatch` is on spot (it jumps around ∓10ms because the latter is inaccurate, but in average they're about equal. If however I compare it with the files from other rythm games (that note at which timestamps the beat kicks), my `StopWatch` turns out to be 50∓25ms early. now one could argue that the files may not be accurate or that the other rythm games have offsets, but after checking countless files in several games I feel save to say that I have this ruled out.

What is causing my offset here and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

I'm measuring the offset like this: whenever I press a key I play a clicky sound (known as "hitsount" in rythm games) and tab along with the song trying to sync not my keyboard input put the resulting hitsound with the beat and measure my average offset. This way I don't need to think about hardware and audio driver latency. Of course I'm not a robot and thus not perfectly accurate, but my inaccuracy is normally spread so I can just take the average and even without that I am at least accurate enough to be able to tell that something's wrong.

Comment: Surely that is because you get the position of the buffer, not of the device.  It is always ahead to ensure the device does not run out of data.  It doesn't look like AsioOut make it easy to fix that, I doubt that its PlayLatency property gets dynamically updated.  But worth a try perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant Please read my edit in the OP. the `AsioOut.PlaybackLatency` property does update dynamically (e.g. when I change the buffer settings in the driver), but while I don't know what exactly it is I do know for sure that it's not what I'm looking for as the number it returns is WAY too high.